# Xamarin forms OnBackButtonPressed not firing on android since upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an app that runs on an android 8.1 device using pre AndroidX Xamarin, Java V8 (C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot)

I now need it run on devices with Android versions 8.1 to 12 so I upgraded all the NuGet packages, set the Target Framework to 12, updated the Java Version to 17 as required.
(C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.4.101-hotspot)

Visual Studio 2019
Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2515 (latest)
All latest required AndroidX packages.
Target Framework Android 12
Minimum Android Version 8.1
Target Android Version 12

All seemed fine but the OnBackButtonPressed event no longer fires on the Android 8.1 device.
It did before the upgrade of all the other components with no code changes by myself.

The OnBackButtonPressed event does fire on an Android 9 and an Android 10 device within the same app (same .apk installed on all three devices).

Does anyone have any idea why this would be or which bit that I updated may have broken it?

This not firing ->>>

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    myViewModel.DoCancel();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So for Android 8.1, this method is never called? If yes can you check other devices below Android 9 and see if this issue also occurs on them?

Comment: I did a test, the `OnBackButtonPressed` event could been fired on an android emulator(android 8.1).

Comment: Unfortunately the only other device I have (Android 7) is faultly.

Comment: I have now tried running it in an Android 8.1 emulator and it is not calling the OnBackButtonPressed method when running here either. Maybe the press is being intercepted elsewhere in my app, although it used to work.
I'll strip down the app to basics and do some more testing.

Comment: @FreakyAli I have now tested this on Android 7.1, 8.1, 9 and 10 and OnBackButtonPressed does not fire on versions below 9 but I have more info. See next comment.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT The problem seems to be this: I open a new view and focus on the first Entry. The soft keyboard pops us. Pressing the back button causes the keyboard to close as it should. Pressing the back button again does nothing (does not fire OnBackButtonPressed).
If I do not automatically focus on the Entry (no soft keyboard popup), pressing the back button does fire OnBackButtonPressed, but if I tap on the Entry, the keyboard pops up and I have the same problem.

Comment: This is really interesting can you create a sample GitHub project that can demo this error.

Comment: Hi @FreakyAli here it is: https://github.com/jadinning/OnBackButtonPressed

Comment: Ok. This seems to have broken in Xamarin Forms Ver 5.0.0.2478. If I revert to Ver 5.0.0.2401 the problem disappears.

Comment: I have reported it on the Xamarin.Forms GitHub and will see what happens.

Comment: I see good job!